# I want to communicate between goroutines and block main thread indefinitely

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

How do i block the the main func and allow goroutines communicate through channels the following code sample throws me an error

0fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {
   ch := make(chan int)

   go func() {
       value := <-ch
       fmt.Print(value) // This never prints!
   }()

   go func() {
       for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
           time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
           ch <- i
       }
   }()

   c := make(chan int)
   <-c
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this? If `GOMAXPROCS` is greater than 1, then it will print it `0`, then deadlock.

Comment: It prints nothing in my case, just throws that error

Comment: Sure it prints. You're showing the output yourself: `0fatal error ...`. The `0` at the beginning of the line is from the print statement.

Comment: Wow .. Actually, Your response was king about this. My code actually works. The problem was i wasn't ending well so when all goroutines sleep .. it deadlocks.

Comment: move on of the goroutines to a for loop in main if it deadlock because main is not doing anything it means you should probaly do one of your routines in the main function,

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to print all value `[0:99]`. Then you need loop in 1st `go routine`.

And also, you need to pass signal to break loop

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    stopProgram := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            value := <-ch
            fmt.Println(value)
        }
        // Send signal through stopProgram to stop loop
        stopProgram <- true
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            ch <- i
        }
    }()

    // your problem will wait here until it get stop signal through channel
    <-stopProgram
}
```

Comment: Thanks as well! .. for the loop in the first go routine. I have a better understanding of it now.